# Passing a connected socket

Tags: c#, silverlight, sockets, tcp

Sorry in advance if this question makes no sense, I am very new to all this but I have a worry I would like to tackle.

So below is part of a class I have created to handle the connection to a audio/video server, the idea is this connection object is then passed to the Call object which handles all the audio and video functions.

```
class Connection{

private socket connection_socket;

    public void Connect(string IP_Address)
    {
        connection_socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        SocketAsyncEventArgs socketEventArg = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();

        socketEventArg.Completed += onConnectCompleted;
        connection_socket.ConnectAsync(socketEventArg);
    }
}
```

Below is how I copy over the connection object to the other classes, it is part of the constructor for AudioCall and VideoCall which then in turn copies it to the _connection variable in the Call class.

```
public class AudioCall : Call
{
    public AudioCall(Connection connection)
    {
        _connection = connection;
    }
```

My worry is and I really hope someone can understand the logic behind it is that because the  connection object is actually a connection, I have used ConnectASync and it has connected that when I copy this connection over it will not work as intended. Should I be copying it down as a reference so the actual connection object is being used or will it work the way it is? I don't fully understand how Sockets work so I have no idea at the moment.

I hope someone can help and thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. You are already passing the connection as a reference since connection is a class. What do you mean by _it will not work as intended_?

Comment: So the way I was taught the line _connection = connection would work is that connection would be duplicated and then applied to _connection, if I have connected through connection is the duplicated version still going to be connected to the port? Sorry if this doesn't make sense, I am trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every object in C# (excluding ValueTypes like int etc.) is passed by reference. So if this `Connection` object is working for one Class, every other will do fine, too. 
Only way to get it to fail would be to pass it to another node with different network properties (e.g. through Middleware).

Comment: @user345453 On a side note to be more clear: `struct`s are also not passed by reference.

Comment: Ok thanks! I don't really know how to use structs at the moment but at least I know for when I learn!